# Proving weak induction implies the Well-Ordering Principle

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, induction

In proving that weak induction implies the Well-Ordering Principle, are we not actually proving that weak induction implies the existence of a particular partial ordering $\leq$ on $N$ such that it is a well-ordering with $x\leq y \implies x\leq S(y)$?

Edit: Here, $S$ is the successor function on $N$.

Comment: [The mathematical induction is logically equivalent to the well-ordering principle](https://www.math.wustl.edu/~chi/310notesIV.pdf)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA But you need induction for definition of predesessor (in PA)

Comment: @VivaanDaga - not very clear... The WOP is expressed in set language. Thus, the corresponding Math Induction principle will be: if $1 \in S$ and if $k \in S$ then $k' \in S$, then $S=\mathbb N$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: *Therefore $m \neq 1$ and so by one of the homework 2 problems there is some $q \in \mathbf{N}$ such that $m = q'$.*  How do establish that without induction?  How do you know that you're not working in say $\omega 2 \backslash \{0\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you asked about strong induction the other day, I wondered if the well ordering principle was on the way; and here we are.

*are we not actually proving that weak induction implies the existence of a particular partial ordering ≤ on N such that it is a well-ordering with $x \leq y \Rightarrow x \leq S(y)$?*

That would be a sensible thing to do, but it's probably not what's going on here.

I guess you're self-studying, since you said before that you were working within your own framework for the natural numbers; and that you're working with a text that proves that weak induction, strong induction, and well ordering are equivalent.

A text that does that might start with a relatively large set of natural number axioms; the Peano axioms, excluding induction, say; some order laws; and some addition laws.  Or it might derive order from addition; as it seems Mauro Allegranza's lecture notes do.  It might not even state a set of axioms, but just proceed from prexisting informal knowledge: "You already know a lot about the natural numbers, but now we're going to tell you three new things; though it will turn out that they're really just one new thing."

Anyhow, this is at a lower theoretical level than starting with the Peano axioms, constructing the order relations and arithmetic operations, and proving strong induction and well ordering.  Maybe that's why you decided to develop your own framework.

Bottom line:  The question you formulate most likely isn't the same question your text is asking, but a better question.

Comment: I have been trying to formalize some proofs I have found online using my proof checker.  I started with only Peano's Axioms. I first had to construct the addition function, then the partial and strict orderings based on addition. Once I established some required lemmas about the orderings, I didn't need to talk about addition anymore. The statement of the theorem refers to these orderings, so you must say something about them. They aren't just arbitrary binary relations on $N$.

Comment: @DanChristensen: Of course, there is a canonical order, which is just the order consistent with succession, so that for any natural number $a$, $a < S(a)$.